# Create an activerecord for using more than one table

Tags: php, activerecord, model, yii2

I want to create an active record in yii2, same as other models based on **activerecord** but the difference is that i want use more than one table.

For example, I have a table in database called `orders`  and another table `order-items`

An **order item** is a product that buy user in order and with *order-id* is connected to `orders` table. Now i want a model for controlling both and use active records features.

For example I could get customer *id* that saved in order table and also an array of product that saved in `order-items`.

Look code below:

```
//get name of customer that saved in order table

$customer = $model->customer;

//get an array of products saved in order-item

$items = $model->items;

//get number of item 3 saved in order-item

$num = $items[3]->number;
```

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relational-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have your own activerecord using two table you should rewrite some functions of `baseActiveRecord` class.

The instruction is like below but you should test and change it in your own case:

1. Define one table as base table.
2. Rewrite `attributes()` method and define some new attribute may exist in table2.
3. Rewrite `find()` method or create an new `ActiveQuery` class to use in find method to create some complex select or join when using find in your searches and select all fields in table 1 and table 2.
4. Rewrite you `save()` and `update()` method of active record to save table 2 fields in database.

Be aware to use transaction in your Rewrited save and update method when saving data in database.

Answer (score 0):

It is better If you can use the relation in activerecord class.

[Refer this link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relational-data)

Comment: Yes.  I read that but i would not create a model for some tabels.

Comment: @Amin You can use the yii\db\Query to perform your SELECT query. [Here is Link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html)

Comment: So i can't use active record features for order-items tabel?